# Run time error '1004' Invalid number of arguments

Tags: excel, vba

im been working with this table in a search and modify formulary in VBA excel, but it keeps showing me the 1004 error, what its supposed to find the type of payment in the K column, there is no empty spaces in that column so the error shouldn´t appear

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBNYT.png)

```
Private Sub ShowEst_Change()

Dim ESTADOPAGO As String
Dim COD As Integer
Dim BaseD As Worksheet: Set BaseD = Sheets("BASE DE DATOS")
Dim RangoT As Range: Set RangoT = BaseD.Range("A:N")
COD = BCN.ShowCOD.Value


ESTADOPAGO = Application.VLookup(COD, BaseD, RangoT, 11, False)


Me.ShowEst.Value = ESTADOPAGO
End Sub
```

Comment: vlookup takes 4 arguments and you're providing 5....  Remove the `BaseD`

Comment: you need (criteria,range,column,false), you don't have that. What is  `BCN.ShowCOD.Value` ?